# Passing a C# string to batch

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I looked around for a while and didn't find many promising articles on the question I have.

I am attempting to write a program that will query users for the path to a file using the openFileDialog and saving the output to a string in C#.  What I want to do with it, is use said path in a command script that will copy the file to another part of the computer for use by the program that I am writing.

I am pretty new to C#, so the dummy version, if possible, would be appreciated.  I so far understand that I have to set up a new process to run batch commands in general, but I never could find good examples of how to pass C# strings to the batch script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use .NET's built in [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method? You can use a [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.aspx) to make this occur on a different thread, also.

If you must spin up a separate process, then you can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) with ProcessInfo set up to the path and pass the arguments in that way.

Comment: it *could be* that script does much more then just copy, it's already written by someone, and it works, so rewriting it is non desirable...

Comment: I was unaware of there being a copy script.  I apologize, I am pretty new to C# and have only experienced a crash course in the past couple days with a scattered knowledge of programming.

Comment: @StephenR No problem, that is why I suggested that over a direct answer to your question. I have updated my answer for Tigran in case you must spin up another process, also

Comment: A bit off topic from the original question, but when I try to use the File.copy method, it doesn't recognize 'File'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Disregard that question regarding File copy...I realized I didn't have the IO library included.

Comment: @StephenR You can delete comments FYI :) If you hover near the end of the line an X will appear

Answer (score 0):

If your script is long, I would use a `StringBuilder` then write the string to a file:

```
// set srcFilename and xcopyOptions (like /Y, for example)

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append( "XCOPY " )
  .Append( xcopyOptions )
  .Append( " " )
  .Append( srcFilename )
  .Append( " " )
  .AppendLine( dstDir );

// repeat for as many copy commands as you want
// ...

File.WriteAllText( scriptFilename, sb.ToString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already available post, if you *really* want to use a batch, to pass a variable to it is the same like a pass arguments to an executable.

- instance process , where "ececutable" is a batch file
- assign arguments, which will be passed like a parameters to the variables of the batch.

  Process thisProcess = new Process();
  thisProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //NO NEED OF WINDOW
  thisProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  thisProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"DirectoryOfTheBacth";
  thisProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "BatchFileName";
  thisProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "parameters";
  thisProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //NO SHELL EXECUTE
  thisProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //STDO REDIRECTION, SO WE CAN READ WHAT IS HAPPENNING
  thisProcess.Start();  // FINALLY, START PROCESS

[How to pass parameter from C# to a batch file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/2a27f180-b880-4da1-832b-b71997eea2a1)